# Proving authorship and names on public magazines when name in publications does not match name in passport

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, authorship, personal-name

My official passport name is very long Mukhammadyusuf Fakhriddinov that's why I use Yusuf Fakhriddinov on my publications, also on most websites I use shorter name. Will it cause any confusion in the future and what should I do if someone asks to prove that publication is mine.
Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a *shorter* name. Yes, you can.

Try to be '*unique*' within your organisation. Obviously, if you move to other organisations (change job), you cannot guarantee uniqueness.

> Will it cause any confusion in the future and what should I do if someone asks to prove that publication is mine

Given that the uniqueness of your '*known*' name might not be unique at all material time over your career, what you can do is to register an [identity on ORCID](https://orcid.org/) with your name and include the *shorter* one as *also known as*.

Try to be ***consistent*** in your research engagements (journal, conf, grant, reports ...).
Within your field, put *a face* to your known name (in networking , conferences...).

If for any reasons you're ask to prove *identity* (your publication),

- show your ORCID, and
- (relevant) correspondence for the publication. This might just be email or if  need be, extracts from journal or conf submission process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's okay to use a shorter name.

But make sure that:

1. Your Department is aware of your assumed name for publications so that calls can be redirected to you.
2. That no one else in your Department has a name (or assumed name) close to your assumed name at the time of publication.